# How To Extrude These Cubes Array?

Tags: freecad

I apologize if the questions sounds stupid, I want to extrude these cubes only, I tried to select all, the freecad froze, and when I select the edges, it also say, no shapes selected for extrusion, can someone help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: CAD questions are always *very* much on the edge what we answer. What is the specific reason that makes this 3D printing related?

Comment: Suggest you post over at https://forum.freecadweb.org/ All the experts hang out over there. Just be sure to read and obey the pink banner when you post.